# Добавить параметр ко всем get/post-запросам

Tags: .htaccess

Можно ли настроить `.htaccess` так, чтобы автоматически добавлялась пара `test=1234` ко всем *get*- или *post*-запросам?

Comment: Чтобы в адресной строке появлялась пара `test=1234` в параметрах? Если да, то проблема с POST запросами предвидится. Вероятно они будут превращаться в GET запросы при редиректе после добавления пары.

Comment: @Visman, при редиректе с кодом 307 - не будут они никуда превращаться.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, был не в курсе.

Answer (score 2):

В продолжение своего комментария к вопросу.

Если вам редирект не нужен, а нужно просто передать скриптам дополнительный параметр, то можно воспользоваться таким .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# строка параметров пустая
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
# методы GET или POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|POST)$
# добавляем пару
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?test=1234 [L]

# в параметрах нет нужной пары
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !test=1234
# методы GET или POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|POST)$
# добавляем пару
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?test=1234&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```